# Beaufort wind force measure

Tags: oceanography, wind, waves

Beaufort scale relates wind speed and wave height of the ocean surface. Does the wave height in the scale refer to significant wave height or mean wave height?

Comment: @JeopardyTempest i removed my comment,it was just me thinkig out loud.

Comment: It refers to significant wave heights in fully developed seas (away from shore). Significant wave heights are closely related to what the human eye can estimate for wave heights and that is what the Beaufort scale was originally focus on.

Comment: @trondhansen no stress, I do the same :)

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable answers. For fully developed sea we have to take significant wave height for sea state estimation right.

Answer (score 2):

The scale refers to the significant wave height H1/3, which is defined as the mean height of the higher third of all waves occurring in a sea area at a given time.

Further reading (but in german):
https://www.dwd.de/DE/service/lexikon/begriffe/S/Signifikante_Wellenhoehe.html?view=renderHelp&nn=17570

[image]

Fig. [Source](https://www.scribd.com/doc/208117763/Beaufort-Scale-of-Wind-Force-and-Its-Probable-Wave-Height)